# Performance issue - slow query in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, sql

When I check `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` in mysql I got below query. It heavily uses CPU (more than 100%). We have a separate server for mysql(64GB RAM).

```
INSERT INTO `search_tmp_598075de5c7e67_73335919` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, MAX(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0)) * 1) AS score FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` AS `search_index` LEFT JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `cea` ON search_index.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `category_ids_index` ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `rating` ON `rating`.`entity_pk_value`=`search_index`.entity_id AND `rating`.entity_type = 1 AND `rating`.store_id  =  1 WHERE (category_ids_index.category_id = 2299)) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC LIMIT 10000
```

Why it uses my full CPU resources?

Where I find the code to create the above query?

Comment: Hello Bilal, Have you got the solution on the same?

Comment: create index resolved the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply. what do you mean by create index? have you run the magento reindex all or you have done something else?

Comment: create index to the column.... something like `create index idx_catalog_product_flat_1_visibility on catalog_product_flat_1 (visibility);`

Answer (score 1):

For thos who are still looking for the solution below is the solution.

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360059449112-MDVA-21095-INSERT-INTO-search-tmp-never-ends-after-mass-attribute-update

Patch is located at https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/blob/magento_magento2_34529/patches/os/MDVA-21095_2.3.2.patch

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15545

There are some great suggestions here.